# uninitialized constant error when trying to update the image file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am trying to use and learn carrierwave. My problem is that I am able to upload files, but when trying to edit them I am getting the error `uninitialized constant ImageFile`

Heres my `images_controller.rb`

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_image, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /images
  # GET /images.json
  def index
    @images = Image.all
  end

  # GET /images/1
  # GET /images/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /images/new
  def new
    @image = Image.new
  end

  # GET /images/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /images
  # POST /images.json
  def create
    @image = Image.new(image_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @image.save
        format.html { redirect_to @image, notice: 'Image was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @image }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /images/1
  # PATCH/PUT /images/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @image.update(image_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @image, notice: 'Image was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @image }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /images/1
  # DELETE /images/1.json
  def destroy
    @image.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to images_url, notice: 'Image was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_image
      @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def image_params
      params.require(:image).permit(:Title, :ImageFile, :Comments)
    end


end
```

and this is the _form.html.erb used in both new and edit

```
<%= form_for @image, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <% if @image.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@image.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this image from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @image.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :Title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :ImageFile %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :ImageFile %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Comments %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :Comments %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and here is the image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :Comments, :ImageFile, :Title
  mount_uploader :ImageFile, ImageCreatorUploader
end
```

please help

Comment: Can you share the schema of `images` table from `db/schema.rb` file? Add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your `Image` class. you are not mounting the uploader correctly. You are passing in a symbol of a classname to the `mount_uploader` method. You need to pass a symbol of the field name. Replace:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :ImageFile, ImageCreatorUploader
end
```

With:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image_file, ImageCreatorUploader
end
```

Method names should not be capitalised. Only class names.

Also, since you are using strong_parameters, you don't need `attr_accessible`. You've commented the line out, but I figured I would point this out. You've also capitalised your attribute names here, which is not correct. Use `snake_case`.

Comment: Now i am getting new  errors
undefined method `image_file_changed?'

Comment: @SouravMoitra do you mind marking an accepted answer if this answer, or another, helped you in the end? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In ruby, attribute names, variable names, method names should all start with a small letter. Names starting with Capital letters are considered constants, and class names.

Change all references to your class's attributes (`:Title`, `:ImageFile`, `:Comments`) to `snake_case` (`:title`, `:image_file`, `:comments`)